# Silverlight: how to navigate to page in class library

Tags: silverlight

I have a bunch of reusable pages that I want to put into a class library.  So I have edited my MainPage.xml ('Moe.Tactical.Generic.Silverlight' is the name of the class library)

```
<uriMapper:UriMapper>
  <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Views/{path}" MappedUri="/Moe.Tactical.Generic.Silverlight;component/Views/{path}" />
  <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
</uriMapper:UriMapper>
```

Then I assign the url in code, but I get the error: Page not found: "/Moe.Tactical.Generic.Silverlight;component/Views/GenericView?page=Maintanance"

I assign the Uri via

```
return new Uri(@"/" + pageType + "?page=" + page.Name, UriKind.Relative);
```

have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry -- my first answer didn't apply.  In your case, your mapping looks like this:

```
  <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Views/{path}" MappedUri="/Moe.Tactical.Generic.Silverlight;component/Views/{path}" />
```

The Uri you've tried to navigate to doesn't match this pattern.  You'll end up with something like: "/MyPageType?page=SomeName", which doesn't match "/Views/{path}".  To make your Uri match the pattern, consider something like:

```
return new Uri(@"/Views/" + pageType + ".xaml?page=" + page.Name, UriKind.Relative);
```

Note the extra "Views/" and ".xaml" in the Uri compared to the example you have in your question.

Comment: so now I get the uri: /Views/Moe.Tactical.Generic.Silverlight;component/Views/GenericView.xaml?page=Maintanance... still no dice

Comment: What are your mappings/navigation uris now?  It looks like you've got an extra "/Views" in there at the beginning.  It should just be "/Moe.Tactical.Generic.Silverlight;component/Views/GenericView.xaml?page=Maintenance" after mapping.

Comment: yea, that was from you comment above - "Note the extra Views/", however I have played around a bit, including removing that additional Views and I still can't navigate

Comment: Is the assembly containing the pages referenced by your application, or are you loading it dynamically (through MEF, Prism, or your own solution)?  What is the error you're getting now?